# Displaying a result in a textbox on a button click (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am new to ASP.Net and would like some help with a simple scenario:

Currently in my web application I have one button and one textbox in my web application. When I click the button I want to display a result in the text box.

How should I do this?

Comment: Um. have you tried write the code yourself?  Something like TextBox1.Text = "sdfgsdfhsdghsdgh" ??? are you receiving an error message?  Sorry, but I just dont understand what the question really is: How do I set the text on a textbox?  How do I add an event handler to a button?  which is it?

Comment: You did not feel like going through one asp.net tutorial? Just one...

Comment: seriously.  you're wasting space on this forum

Comment: Tomorrow we shall go over how you can have 2 buttons. Clicking on one button will populate a label with "Hello World!". Clicking on the second button will populate the same label with "Goodbye Cruel World!".

Comment: Everyone gets a +1 for taking the time to answer!!!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using ASP.NET WebForms you can add a Click event handler to the button to set the text box's text:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyTextBox.Text = "Text to display";
}
```

You can either use autowireup to get the event handler wired to the button, or explicitly assign the event handler to the event in the Page_Load() method.

The easiest way to assign the event to the button is to declare it in the .aspx code like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

It will be done automatically if you doubleclick this button in the designer mode.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info Kirill - been a while since I've worked in webforms so the specifics were a bit rusty.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the result in a button Click Handler like...

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Result Text.....";
}
```

There is a `Text` property of Textbox controls, that is used to `Set/Get` values.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public void button_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{

    txt.Text = "Testing";      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
button.Click += (s, e) => { textbox.Text = "whoa!"; }
```

Comment: +1: forget the earlier comment :)

Comment: actually. wouldn't 's' be the sender and thus a reference to the button?  I like where your heads at though.

Comment: Its a valid solution, but I'd never suggest this to anyone who is clearly very new to C# / ASP.Net development.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void button_Click(object sender,  EventArgs e)
{
    string str="String";
    int i=100;
    textbox1.Text = "string text";  
    //or
    textbox1.Text = str;  
   //or
    textbox1.Text = i.Tostring();
  //and same as above for other types i.e, convert to string when assigning to textBox because textbox takes value as string only
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     TextBox1.Text = "Text Message";
}
```

Refer this link to get started: http://www.knowdotnet.com/

For submit button properties check this: [MSDN Button Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.aspx)